# why SQLite database size is 0KB after installation?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, installation

I made a windows application with sqlite database, i kept the database at bin\debug and i am retrieving the database path like this:

```
currentDir=System.Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString();
```

It is working fine at debug mode but when i create the setup and install it then database is stored somewhere in c:\program files.. But the problem is it shows the database **file size 0KB** , when i replace this file with correct database, it works well. but i don't know why this problem occurs, why database size get decreased to 0KB ?

Need Help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally got it, because i was not including sqlite database while creating the database

```
Application Folder > Add > File > Choose the database
```

and problem is gone.Silly mistake.